# Multidisplay error on canvas in Unity 5.5.0b11

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine

I'm in a project right now in which I'm having a trouble with Canvas multidisplay in Unity 5.5.0b11. While testing in a single display it works perfectly but when using multidisplay it doesn't answer the orders i ask for as it should do (by clicking somewhore, clicks somewhere else or copy something....). As well i tried to work with v5.4 but canvas didn't work at all, so then I made some research and found that in v5.5b it was solved. Any idea how to make multidisplay work properly in Unity 5.5.0b11?

Thank for your attention,

Comment: Did you find the bug explained it Joan ?

Comment: Finaly there was no problem with canvas. There was a script with MouseDown and MouseUp that don't work. So I found that if I turn off and on my Main Camera it works xD